# OpenLayers layer disappear when zooming out

Tags: openlayers

I generated a map using openlayer and I'm adding a baundary using openSpace, OpenSpace.Layer.Boundary, but when I zoom out after a specific level my layer disappears, how can I keep the layer displaying? OpenSpace uses openLayer in the background, so if you can tell me how you would prevent a layer from disappearing on zooming out I guess I can apply the solution to openSpace.

Thank you

Comment: you may paste your code here. And we can help you to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked for scale based rules? It's very common to to use them, and maybe somewhere in the process you involountarily set them or they were generated for you.

Can you post some code to show what you try to do?